# How to uninstall and install a specific python version

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip

Am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS by default I have 3.8.2 as python version but when I issue **sudo apt-get update** its getting updating to 3.8.5 I need 3.8.2 as the version.How to uninstall 3.8.5 and install 3.8.2?

Answer (score 1):

It might not directly answer your question, but it's an alternative solution. You could install something like [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#installation) which simplifies the process of handling different python versions. After installing it, `pyenv install 3.8.2 && pyenv global 3.8.2` should do the trick.

Comment: Hi @Bogsan Am using ubuntu 20.04 ,I have two versions of python installed  3.8.5 and 3.8.2. How to make Python 3.8.2 as the default version for python
```
$ python3 -V
Python 3.8.5

$ python3.8 -V
Python 3.8.2 ```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, one that comes to mind is something like `echo "alias python=$(which python3.8)"  >> ~/.bashrc` (or .zshrc if you use zsh).